# Reading NITF files using python

Tags: python

Did any one read NITF file format using Python?
The NITF file extension is known as the National Imagery Transmission Format.

[Info](https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/nitf)

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Imagery_Transmission_Format)

Comment: What did you end up using?  Do you know if there is a package in conda which reads nitfs?

Answer (score 6):

there is a python [NITF](https://github.com/hobu/nitro/tree/master/python/nitf) module.

usage:

```
from nitf import *

fname = 'path/to/file.NTF'
handle = IOHandle(fname)
reader = Reader()
record = reader.read(handle)
segment = record.getImages()[0]
imReader = reader.newImageReader(0)
```

Comment: That's a mirror of a project that used to be on Sourceforge but recently moved to Github themselves, now at https://github.com/mdaus/nitro